# Better way to add time to a timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I like to add a 5 minutes to a timestamp:

```
SELECT timestamp+300 FROM table
```

works with minutes (5*60 = 300) But if I like to add a month or a year I can't calculate in seconds.

I came up with this query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) FROM table
```

So I can go with years as well:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) + INTERVAL 2 YEAR) FROM table
```

Is this "the" solution or is there a more, elegant way?

Comment: Yes. It's either this or you do it from a server side language

Comment: So I have to convert from timestamp to date and back to timestamp. Better would be a date field

Comment: Well, MYSQL is smart , you could also use DATE_ADD : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,5,'2003-01-02'))